# dplyr tidyr – How to generate case_when with dynamic conditons?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, rlang

Is there a way to dynamically/programmatically generate `case_when` conditions in `dplyr` with different column names and/or different numbers of conditions? I have an interactive script that I'm trying to convert into a function. There's a lot of repeated code in the `case_when` statements and I'm wondering if it can be automated somehow without my needing to write everything from scratch again and again.

Here's a dummy dataset:

```
test_df = tibble(low_A=c(5, 15, NA),
                 low_TOT=c(NA, 10, NA),
                 low_B=c(20, 25, 30),
                 high_A=c(NA, NA, 10),
                 high_TOT=c(NA, 40, NA),
                 high_B=c(60, 20, NA))

expected_df = tibble(low_A=c(5, 15, NA),
                     low_TOT=c(NA, 10, NA),
                     low_B=c(20, 25, 30),
                     ans_low=c(5, 10, 30),
                     high_A=c(NA, NA, 10),
                     high_TOT=c(NA, 40, NA),
                     high_B=c(60, 20, NA),
                     ans_high=c(60, 40, 10))

> expected_df
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  low_A low_TOT low_B ans_low high_A high_TOT high_B ans_high
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     5      NA    20       5     NA       NA     60       60
2    15      10    25      10     NA       40     20       40
3    NA      NA    30      30     10       NA     NA       10
```

The logic I want is that if the `._TOT` column has a value, use that. If not, then try column `._A`, and if not, then column `._B`. Note that I intentionally didn't put `._TOT` as the first column for a group. I could just use coalesce() in that case, but I want a general solution irrespective of column order.

Of course, all of this is easy to do with a couple of `case_when` statements. My issues are that:

1. I'm trying to make a general function and so don't want interactive/tidy evaluation.
2. I have a whole bunch of columns like this. All ending with one of `_TOT, _A, _B` but with different prefixes (e.g., `low_TOT, low_A, low_B, high_TOT, high_A, high_B,.....` and I don't want to rewrite a bunch of `case_when` functions again and again.

What I have right now looks like this (where I'm writing a `case_when` for each prefix):

```
def my_function = function(df) { 
    df %>% mutate(
          # If a total low doesn't exist, use A (if exists) or B (if exists)
          "ans_low" := case_when(
            !is.na(.data[["low_TOT"]]) ~ .data[["low_TOT"]],
            !is.na(.data[["low_A"]]) ~ .data[["low_A"]],
            !is.na(.data[["low_B"]]) ~ .data[["low_B"]],
          ),

          # If a total high doesn't exist, use A (if exists) or B (if exists)
          "ans_high" := case_when(
            !is.na(.data[["high_TOT"]]) ~ .data[["high_TOT"]],
            !is.na(.data[["high_A"]]) ~ .data[["high_R"]],
            !is.na(.data[["high_B"]]) ~ .data[["high_B"]],
              
         # Plus a whole bunch of similar case_when functions...
}
```

And what I'd like is to ideally get a way to dynamically generate `case_when` functions with different conditions so that I'm not writing a new `case_when` each time by exploiting the fact that:

1. All the three conditions have the same general form, and the same structure for the variable names, but with a different prefix (`high_`, `low_`, etc.).
2. They have the same formula of the form `!is.na( .data[[ . ]]) ~ .data[[ . ]]`, where the **dot**(`.`) is the dynamically generated name of the column.

What I'd like is something like:

```
def my_function = function(df) { 
    df %>% mutate(
          "ans_low" := some_func(prefix="Low"),
          "ans_high" := some_func(prefix="High")
}
```

I tried creating my own `case_when` generator to replace the standard `case_when` as shown below, but I'm getting an error. I'm guessing that's because `.data` doesn't really work outside of the tidyverse functions?

```
some_func = function(prefix) {
  case_when(
    !is.na(.data[[ sprintf("%s_TOT", prefix) ]]) ~ .data[[ sprintf("%s_TOT", prefix) ]],
    !is.na(.data[[ sprintf("%s_A", prefix) ]]) ~ .data[[ sprintf("%s_A", prefix) ]],
    !is.na(.data[[ sprintf("%s_B", prefix) ]]) ~ .data[[ sprintf("%s_B", prefix) ]]
  )
}
```

Something else I'm curious about is making an even more general `case_when` generator. In the examples thus far, it's only the names (prefix) of the columns that are changing. What if I wanted to

1. change the number and names of suffixes (e.g., `high_W, high_X, high_Y, high_Z, low_W, low_X, low_Y, low_Z, .......`) and so make a character vector of suffixes an argument of `some_func`
2. change the form of the formula. Right now, it's of the form `!is.na(.data[[ . ]]) ~ .data[[ . ]]` for all the conditions, but what if I wanted to make this an argument of `some_func`? For example, `!is.na(.data[[  . ]]) ~ sprintf("%s is missing", .)`

I'd be happy with just getting it to work with different prefixes but it'd be very cool to understand how I could achieve something even more general with arbitrary (but common) suffixes and arbitrary formulae such that I can do `some_func(prefix, suffixes, formula)`.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you are just trying to get the first non-NA value, a function like `coalesce()` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: See now. I added a simple data set as an example and rewrote the question to be clearer and shorter. It's still a little long because, really, I'm asking 3 questions about the increasing levels of generality that I'd like (and to see if that's possible, to begin with).

Comment: A `coalesce()` could be a potential answer, but I'm more interested in dynamically generating conditions (`is.na` is just the particular example here and `coalesce` also requires a specific column order). I'm really trying to understand how to **program** with dplyr better and achieve higher levels of abstraction/generality.

Comment: I also just tried `coalese()` with a prior reordering of the columns but it gives the same major issue: I have to write a whole bunch of `coalesce` statements now. I want to exploit the common prefix of the groups of columns so I don't have to write 10 different `case_when` or `coalese` statements.

Comment: Why not split up the columns by prefix, using the results of `gsub("_(TOT|[A-Z]+)$", "", ...)` on `colnames()` to determine how they're split up?  This accounts for indefinitely many column suffixes: `*_TOT`, `*_A`, `*_B`, `*_C`, ..., `*_Z`, `*_AA`, `*_AB`, ..., and so forth.  Then for each of those splits (`"low_"` and `"high_"`), sort their `colnames()` by suffix, given by `str_extract("_(TOT|[A-Z]+)$")`; you'll obviously have to reorder `"_TOT"` as coming first.  Then `mutate(paste0("ans_", prefix) = coalesce(everything()))`, and `cbind()` or `bind_cols()` all results back together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a custom `case_when` function that you can call with `purrr::reduce` and a vector of strings parts of your variable names (in the example `c("low", "high")`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_case_when <- function(df, x) {
  
  mutate(df,
         "ans_{x}" := case_when(
           !is.na(!! sym(paste0(x, "_TOT"))) ~ !! sym(paste0(x, "_TOT")),
           !is.na(!! sym(paste0(x, "_A"))) ~ !! sym(paste0(x, "_A")),
           !is.na(!! sym(paste0(x, "_B"))) ~ !! sym(paste0(x, "_B"))
           )
  )
}

test_df %>% 
  reduce(c("low", "high"), my_case_when, .init = .)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>   low_A low_TOT low_B high_A high_TOT high_B ans_low ans_high
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     5      NA    20     NA       NA     60       5       60
#> 2    15      10    25     NA       40     20      10       40
#> 3    NA      NA    30     10       NA     NA      30       10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I also have a package on Github {dplyover} which is made for this kind of cases. For your example with more than two variables I would use `dplyover::over` together with a special syntax to evaluate strings as variable names. We can further use `dplyover::cut_names("_TOT")` to extract the string parts of the variable names that come before or after `"_TOT"` (in the example this is `"low"` and `"high"`).

We can either use `case_when`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

test_df %>% 
  mutate(over(cut_names("_TOT"),
              list(ans = ~ case_when(
                  !is.na(.("{.x}_TOT")) ~ .("{.x}_TOT"),
                  !is.na(.("{.x}_A")) ~ .("{.x}_A"),
                  !is.na(.("{.x}_B")) ~ .("{.x}_B")
                  )),
              .names = "{fn}_{x}")
         )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>   low_A low_TOT low_B high_A high_TOT high_B ans_low ans_high
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     5      NA    20     NA       NA     60       5       60
#> 2    15      10    25     NA       40     20      10       40
#> 3    NA      NA    30     10       NA     NA      30       10
```

Or somewhat easier `coalesce`:

```r
test_df %>% 
  mutate(over(cut_names("_TOT"),
              list(ans = ~ coalesce(.("{.x}_TOT"),
                                    .("{.x}_A"),
                                    .("{.x}_B"))),
              .names = "{fn}_{x}")
  )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>   low_A low_TOT low_B high_A high_TOT high_B ans_low ans_high
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     5      NA    20     NA       NA     60       5       60
#> 2    15      10    25     NA       40     20      10       40
#> 3    NA      NA    30     10       NA     NA      30       10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Color me intrigued by `dplyover`!  How might one do this for arbitrarily many suffixes? Consider: `_TOT`, `_A`, `_B`, ..., `_Z`, `_AA`, `_AB`, ..., and so forth; defined by the regex `_(TOT|[A-Z]+)$`.

Comment: @Greg: We can  use regex in the selection functions `cut_names` and `extract_names`. However, within the `case_when` function above, we would need to hard code all suffixes, at least if we use `over`. There are also `over2` and `over2x` which will also allow a `.y` argument , but at the end it depends on how the `case_when` function should look like.

Comment: @Greg, I just found a solution (with some edits of my own), that allows for arbitrary suffixes. Look up my solution below.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated Solution**
I think this solution solely based on base R may help you.

```
fn <- function(data) {
  
  do.call(cbind, lapply(unique(gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)_.*", "\\1", names(test_df))), function(x) {
    tmp <- test_df[paste0(x, c("_TOT", "_A", "_B"))]
    tmp[[paste(x, "ans", sep = "_")]] <- Reduce(function(a, b) {
      i <- which(is.na(a))
      a[i] <- b[i]
      a
    }, tmp)
    tmp
  }))
}

fn(test_df)

fn(test_df)

   high_TOT high_A high_B high_ans low_TOT low_A low_B low_ans
1       NA     NA     60       60      NA     5    20       5
2       40     NA     20       40      10    15    25      10
3       NA     10     NA       10      NA    NA    30      30
```

Answer (score 6):

At the risk of not answering the question, I think the easiest way to approach this is to just reshape and use `coalesce()`. Your data structure requires two pivots either way (I think) but this requires no careful thinking about what prefixes are present.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_df <- tibble(
  low_A = c(5, 15, NA),
  low_TOT = c(NA, 10, NA),
  low_B = c(20, 25, 30),
  high_A = c(NA, NA, 10),
  high_TOT = c(NA, 40, NA),
  high_B = c(60, 20, NA)
)

test_df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rowid, names_to = c("prefix", "suffix"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = suffix, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(ans = coalesce(TOT, A, B)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-rowid, -prefix), names_to = "suffix") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(prefix, suffix), names_sep = "_", values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#>   rowid low_A low_TOT low_B low_ans high_A high_TOT high_B high_ans
#>   <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     5      NA    20       5     NA       NA     60       60
#> 2     2    15      10    25      10     NA       40     20       40
#> 3     3    NA      NA    30      30     10       NA     NA       10
```

Note also that `case_when` has no tidy evaluation, and so just not using `mutate` simplifies your `some_func` a lot. You already got an answer using `!!sym` inside mutate, so here is a version that illustrates a simpler way. I prefer not to use tidyeval unless necessary because I want to use a `mutate` chain, and here it's not really needed.

```r
some_func <- function(df, prefix) {
  ans <- str_c(prefix, "_ans")
  TOT <- df[[str_c(prefix, "_TOT")]]
  A <- df[[str_c(prefix, "_A")]]
  B <- df[[str_c(prefix, "_B")]]
  
  df[[ans]] <- case_when(
    !is.na(TOT) ~ TOT,
    !is.na(A) ~ A,
    !is.na(B) ~ B
  )
  df
}

reduce(c("low", "high"), some_func, .init = test_df)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>   low_A low_TOT low_B high_A high_TOT high_B low_ans high_ans
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     5      NA    20     NA       NA     60       5       60
#> 2    15      10    25     NA       40     20      10       40
#> 3    NA      NA    30     10       NA     NA      30       10
```

Comment: [My instinct](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121044897) too was to just _"to just reshape and use `coalesce()`"_.  I am curious, though: how might we generalize to arbitrarily many alphabetical suffixes `_A`, `_B`, ..., `_Z`, `_AA`, `_AB`, and so forth?  And for prefixes that might themselves contain `_`, as with `another_prefix_A`?  Perhaps by pivoting the column names into a `name` column, and then by splitting each `name` into (1) the substring matching the regex `_(TOT|[A-Z]+)$`, and (2) the substring of everything that came before.

Comment: To handle arbitrary suffixes, I'd probably want to order the list of suffixes and splice into `coalesce`. For complex prefixes, `pivot_longer` supports `names_pattern`, so you can use use a regex to select the groups you want (e.g. `(^.*)_([^_]+$)` would (I think) make the suffix the last `_` before the end of the string, and the prefix everything before that underscore.

Comment: I really liked your base R solution (way more than the multiple pivots). Unfortunately, yours doesn't really solve the problem of generating `case_when` conditions dynamically so I had to choose TimeTeaFan's as the accepted answer. But if I had to do this again, I'd definitely use your base R solution which is much easier to grasp.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all your answers folks! Calum You's answer specifically made me realise that sticking to the Tidyverse all the time isn't necessarily the best and sometimes base R has a better, simpler, and more elegant solution.

Thans to a ton of searching and [this excellent post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/case-when-pattern-dynamically-generated/96790) by noahm on the RStduio community, I was also able to come up with a solution of my own that does what I was looking for:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(glue)

make_expr = function(prefix, suffix) {
  rlang::parse_expr(glue::glue('!is.na(.data[[\"{prefix}_{suffix}\"]]) ~ .data[[\"{prefix}_{suffix}\"]]'))
}

make_conds = function(prefixes, suffixes){
  map2(prefixes, suffixes, make_expr)
}

ans_df = test_df %>%  
    mutate(
        "ans_low" := case_when(
            !!! make_conds( prefixes=c("low"), suffixes=c("TOT", "A", "B") ) 
        ),
        "ans_high" := case_when(
            !!! make_conds( prefixes=c("high"), suffixes=c("TOT", "A", "B") ) 
        )
    )

# The ans is the same as the expected solution
> all_equal(ans_df, expected_df)
[1] TRUE
```

I've also checked that this works inside of a function (which was another important consideration for me).

One benefits of this solution is that the suffixes are not hard-coded and achieve at least the first level of generality I was looking for.

I imagine some string manipulation with replacements could possibly also allow for generality with the structure of the formulae. Ultimately, general formulae would require a string templating solution of some sort because with this structure, you can just keep that into glue.

Answer (score 2):

This does not generate any `case_when`, but you can create the two new columns as follows. Of course this could also be a function with `test_df`, `ans_order`, and `and_groups` as arguments.

```r
ans_order <- c('TOT', 'A', 'B')
ans_groups <- c('low', 'high')

test_df[paste0('ans_', ans_groups)] <- 
  apply(outer(ans_groups, ans_order, paste, sep = '_'), 1, 
        function(x) do.call(dplyr::coalesce, test_df[x]))

test_df
#>   low_A low_TOT low_B high_A high_TOT high_B ans_low ans_high
#> 1     5      NA    20     NA       NA     60       5       60
#> 2    15      10    25     NA       40     20      10       40
#> 3    NA      NA    30     10       NA     NA      30       10
```

If you'd rather not use any packages, another option is

```
test_df[paste0('ans_', ans_groups)] <- 
  apply(outer(ans_groups, ans_order, paste, sep = '_'), 1, 
        function(x) Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x), test_df[x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer has been accepted, I feel this can be done (even for any number of column sets) in `dplyr` only without the need of writing a custom function earlier.

```
test_df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('_TOT'), ~ coalesce(., 
                                              get(gsub('_TOT', '_A', cur_column())), 
                                              get(gsub('_TOT', '_B', cur_column()))
                                              ),
                .names = "ans_{gsub('_TOT', '', .col)}"))

# A tibble: 3 x 8
  low_A low_TOT low_B high_A high_TOT high_B ans_low ans_high
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1     5      NA    20     NA       NA     60       5       60
2    15      10    25     NA       40     20      10       40
3    NA      NA    30     10       NA     NA      30       10
```

---

A complete base R approach

```
Reduce(function(.x, .y) {
  xx <- .x[paste0(.y, c('_TOT', '_A', '_B'))]
  .x[[paste0('ans_',.y)]] <- apply(xx, 1, \(.z) head(na.omit(.z), 1))
  .x
}, unique(gsub('([_]*)_.*', '\\1', names(test_df))),
init = test_df)

# A tibble: 3 x 8
  low_A low_TOT low_B high_A high_TOT high_B ans_low ans_high
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1     5      NA    20     NA       NA     60       5       60
2    15      10    25     NA       40     20      10       40
3    NA      NA    30     10       NA     NA      30       10
```